# IEnumerable<XAttribute> is returning Null, Needs to Return Attribute Value

Tags: c#, linq

This is an example xml I just need the Nid attribute

```
<Server>
  <Network Nid="43d5377-0dcd-40e6-b95c-8ee980b1e248">
  <Client_Group id="20">963440d0-96dc-46a4-a54d-7251a65f585f</Client_Group>
  <ClientID id="20">3fc8ffa1-c16b-4d7b-9e55-1e88dfe15277</ClientID>
<Server>
```

This is the IEnumerable for the XAttributes so that we can use Linq to query attributes in a XML Document, using the XElement to access an XML File. for some reason this is returning Null and it needs to be returning the Attributes for attribute names "Nid".

```
 XElement main = XElement.Load(fi.FullName);

IEnumerable<XAttribute> successAttributes =
                 from attribute in main.Attributes()
                 where attribute.Name.LocalName == "Nid"
                 select attribute;
```

this is where I execute the Linq Query to get the attributes in place them in the array

```
foreach (string attribute in successAttributes)
                { 
                    for (int i = 0; i < IntializedPorts.Count(); i++)
                    {
                      //running Intialization
                      IntializedNetworks[i] = attribute.ToString();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: You mean `successAttributes == null`?

Comment: Its returning null cause something is not right with the query

Comment: I just added the XElement the fi.Fullname is the path to the XML Document

Comment: My feeling says there is no `Nid` attribute on the root element of the Xml document...

Comment: Sorry, forgot to display xml, the Nid attribute is in the Parent

Comment: @shawn with the XML, no: it is in the child

Comment: @shawn Refer my answer poster. That may help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you. Everything you wrote that code was right, you just rather use `main.Element("Network").Attributes()` than `main.Attributes()`

```
IEnumerable<XAttribute> successAttributes =
                 from attribute in main.Element("Network").Attributes()
                 where attribute.Name.LocalName == "Nid"
                 select attribute;
```

On behalf of this issue I wrote the below sample program which will yield the expected NID value

```
string strVal = "<Server><Network Nid=\"43d5377-0dcd-40e6-b95c-8ee980b1e248\"/><Client_Group id=\"20\">963440d0-96dc-46a4-a54d-7251a65f585f</Client_Group><ClientID id=\"20\">3fc8ffa1-c16b-4d7b-9e55-1e88dfe15277</ClientID></Server>";

            XElement main = XElement.Load(new StringReader(strVal));

            IEnumerable<XAttribute> successAttributes =
                 from attribute in main.Element("Network").Attributes()
                 where attribute.Name.LocalName == "Nid"
                 select attribute;
```

Comment: Thank you sir, lol I knew I missing something, I had feeling was it was just missing something in text I couldn't place my finger on it

Answer (score 0):

`main` here is the root element: `<Server>` - which does not have a `Nid` attribute.

You want something like:

```
Guid nid = (Guid)main.Element("Network").Attribute("Nid");
```

Or for multiple:

```
Guid[] arr = (from attr in main.DescendentsOrSelf().Attributes("Nid")
              select (Guid)attr).ToArray();
```

Comment: Yeah, but is that going to get all the Nid ids from multiple xml files, the GUID also could be read as string

Comment: @shawn it is unclear what "multiple XML files" you are referring to. And yes, I could read the guid as a string - it feels more natural to use a guid if it is actually a guid, though - but that is subjective.

Comment: actually what I meant was if I have multiple Nid Id's how would that be implemented in an array cause in the Xattributes I am using Enumerable for getting multiple Nid Id's cause I am only showing one in my xml for that xml is a sample

Comment: @shawn pro tip: if you need to get more than be piece of data, then use an example that *includes* more than one piece of data that you want. Will update.

Comment: If you see in my cast of the Xattribute query it calls the query and gets all the Nid Id's and adds them to an Array Called IntializeNetworks[I]